# Using a vector of structs to populate a DirectX D3D10_SUBRESOURCE_DATA

Tags: c++, directx

I have a simple struct that contains vertex information that will end up in a geometry shader:

```
struct SpriteVertex
{
    float topLeft[2];
    float dimensions[2];
    float opacity;  
};
```

I populate a `std::vector<SpriteVertex> m_Sprites` with various values in my Map class (numbers hard-coded in to simplify the example):

```
// the container is defined in the renderer.h:
std::vector<SpriteVertex>* m_SpriteList;


// the rest is the body of renderer.cpp:
SpriteVertex v;

v.topLeft[0] = 0;
v.topLeft[1] = 0;
v.dimensions[0] = 0.08;
v.dimensions[1] = 0.106667;
v.opacity = 1;
m_Sprites.push_back(v);

v.topLeft[0] = 0.08;
v.topLeft[1] = 0;
v.dimensions[0] = 0.08;
v.dimensions[1] = 0.106667;
v.opacity = 1;
m_Sprites.push_back(v);

v.topLeft[0] = 0.16;
v.topLeft[1] = 0;
v.dimensions[0] = 0.08;
v.dimensions[1] = 0.106667;
v.opacity = 1;
m_Sprites.push_back(v);
```

Then, later on in my renderer class, I populate a buffer with this data:

```
D3D10_SUBRESOURCE_DATA initData;
initData.pSysMem = &(m_SpriteList[0]);

D3D10_BUFFER_DESC bd;
bd.Usage = D3D10_USAGE_DEFAULT;
bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(SpriteVertex)*(numSprites);
bd.BindFlags = D3D10_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
bd.MiscFlags = 0;

pD3DDevice->CreateBuffer(&bd, &initData, &pVertexBuffer));

// Set vertex buffer
UINT stride = sizeof(SpriteVertex);
UINT offset = 0;
pD3DDevice->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &pVertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);

pColorMap->SetResource(pTexture1);
for(UINT p = 0; p < techDesc.Passes; p++)
{
    pTechnique->GetPassByIndex(p)->Apply(0);
    pD3DDevice->Draw(numSprites, 0);
}
```

And all I get is a blank screen.

If I replace the vector with a simple array, the sprites are drawn fine:

```
SpriteVertex verts[3];
verts[0].topLeft[0] = 0.0f;
verts[0].topLeft[1] = 0.0f;
verts[0].dimensions[0] = 0.08f;
verts[0].dimensions[1] = 0.106667;
verts[0].opacity = 1;

verts[1].topLeft[0] = 0.08f;
verts[1].topLeft[1] = 0.0f;
verts[1].dimensions[0] = 0.08f;
verts[1].dimensions[1] = 0.106667;
verts[1].opacity = 1;

verts[2].topLeft[0] = 0.16f;
verts[2].topLeft[1] = 0.0f;
verts[2].dimensions[0] = 0.08f;
verts[2].dimensions[1] = 0.106667;
verts[2].opacity = 1;    

D3D10_SUBRESOURCE_DATA initData;
initData.pSysMem = &verts;
```

Obviously I could just create a temp array and populate it with the values from my vector, or just use an array in the first place, but I am under the impression that I can access the 'traditional' array in a vector in this way.

Am I just misusing a pointer or reference somewhere?

Comment: And `numSprites` is correctly initialized in both cases?

Comment: numSprites is `3` in both cases, using the vector I'm setting it from `m_SpriteList->size()`, and for the array, just setting to `3`

Comment: `&(m_SpriteList[0])` is a `SpriteVertex*`, compared to `&verts` that is a `SpriteVertex**`.

Comment: @Martin But in both cases the address will be the same since `&verts == &verts[0]`, but formally incorrect though.

Comment: My only guess is that something has happened with `m_Sprites` between you pushing the data into it and the call to `CreateBuffer`.

Comment: At one point I did loop through the vector in the renderer and `cout` all the values - it seems to be okay right up until the buffer is filled. Am I correct in thinking that as long as the vector is not changed until after the `Draw()` I should be fine?

Comment: I think it should be fine to discard the vector right after the call to CreateBuffer.

Comment: Okay, just a giggle I put the iteration with cout back, right at the end of the render pass, and the vector certainly seems to be full of data. Not sure on the SO etiquette, but the file can be seen here: http://goo.gl/xPWyc

Comment: I would like to know what happens if you actually fill the vector at the same place as you fill the array, i.e. resize it to three and use exactly the same code to set the elements.

Comment: You're pushing onto m_Sprites and reading from m_SpriteList - I presume this is a typo though?

Comment: @EddieEdwards Yes, kind of. The vector is filled in one class, then passed to another. I'll try what Andreas suggested and fill a vector in the renderer, to see what happens.

Comment: You don't have `std::vector<SpriteVertex>* m_SpriteList`, do you?  So you'd need `&((*m_SpriteList)[0])` if so.

Comment: AAh! That was it. I _really_ need to work a bit more on my refs/pointers/etc concepts. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: For archival purposes perhaps add the definition of `m_SpriteList` to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a pointer `std::vector<SpriteVertex>* m_SpriteList` then you need to dereference the pointer first, before applying the `[]` operator, otherwise you just get the address of the pointer.  In this case you need `&((*m_SpriteList)[0])`.

The type system can't help you here as you're writing to a `void *`.  A good idea is to first write to a local pointer `const SpriteVertex * verts = &m_vector[0]` which then catches the mistake with the type system.

Comment: Thank you very much - this nailed it. I've added the specific declaration to the question for clarity - might have saved some time.
Good tip with the local pointer too, thanks again!